# JavaFX SceneBuilder: how to make textarea fill a pane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder, splitpane

I am using a SplitPane control to divide all available space between two text areas allowing users to adjust split position according to their needs.

```
- SplitPane
  - AnchorPane
    - TextArea [1]
  - AnchorPane
    - TextArea [2]
```

Unfortunatelly textareas only take constant amount space (as was defined in SceneBuilder) and refuse to shrink to fill whole area of SplitPane's AnchorPane:

[image]

How to get it fixed up?

Comment: Why wrap them in `AnchorPane`s instead of making the `TextArea`s the items of the `SplitPane`? If you want to keep it this way: Have you set the anchors for the `TextArea`s? (posting the fxml would help allow us to see for ourselfes btw)

Comment: @fabian Yep, you are right! Removing AnchorPane(s) from hierarchy did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggeset to put the AnchorPanes in a GridPane so you can set percentages for the vertical metrics for example (don't remember if this also works with split pane),

and then bind the properties